# SerializationException when deserializing message send through a socket

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, serialization

I am creating a program where I am trying to connect a server and multiple clients through a socket system. For some reason when I deserialize I get an exception.

I made it so that the **first 2 bytes of the first message contains the length** of the message that is coming. (This is so that I can receive messages bigger then the buffer (1024 bytes)). And the mistake I have has probably to do with this code?

**Exception:**

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Binary stream
>   '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid
>   stream or object version change between serialization and
>   deserialization.'

**The base send code is as following:**

```cs
    public void Send(byte[] data)
    {
        if (ClientSocket != null && ClientSocket.Connected)
        {
            ClientSocket.BeginSend(AddSize(data), 0, data.Length, 0, ResponseSend, this);
        }
        else
        {
            ConnectionFailed();
        }
    }

    private byte[] AddSize(byte[] data)
    {
        var newData = BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToUInt16(data.Length));
        Array.Resize(ref newData, sizeof(ushort) + data.Length);
        Array.Copy(data, 0, newData, sizeof(ushort), data.Length);
        return newData;
    }

    private void ResponseSend(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            var bytesSent = ClientSocket.EndSend(ar);
            SendCompleted();
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            ConnectionFailed();
        }
    }
```

**The base receive code is as following:**

```cs
    private const int BufferSize = 1024;

    // Receive buffer.  
    private MemoryStream _bufferStream = new MemoryStream();
    private readonly byte[] _buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    private ushort _messageLength;

    public void Receive()
    {
        if (ClientSocket != null && ClientSocket.Connected)
        {
            ClientSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCommand, this);
        }
        else
        {
            ConnectionFailed();
        }
    }

    private void ReceiveCommand(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
        var client = (BaseClient)ar.AsyncState;

        try
        {
            var bytesRead = ClientSocket.EndReceive(ar);
            if (bytesRead <= 0)
            {
                ConnectionFailed();
                return;
            }

            var messageSizeOffset = 0;
            if (_messageLength == 0)
            {
                _messageLength = GetMessageLength(client._buffer);
                messageSizeOffset = sizeof(ushort);
            }

            _bufferStream.Write(client._buffer, messageSizeOffset, bytesRead - messageSizeOffset);

            if (_bufferStream.Length >= _messageLength)
            {
                var data = Deserialize(_bufferStream);

                //Cleanup
                _messageLength = 0;
                _bufferStream.Dispose();
                _bufferStream = new MemoryStream();

                ReceiveCompleted(data);
            }

            Receive();
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            ConnectionFailed();
        }
    }
```

**And I just use this simple serialize and deserialize functions:**

```cs
    private byte[] Serialize(object item)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, item);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }

    public static object Deserialize(MemoryStream stream)
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
```

Does anybody has any idea why I get this error? Because I have no clue anymore.

I also added a sample on the following link: https://github.com/kevingoos/SocketTest

Comment: [prolly you should set position after writing](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7sDKIZ)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Your first solution with the data.length is the solution, stuppid mistake on my end. If you post this I will set it as solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in `Send`:

```
public void Send(byte[] data)
    {
        if (ClientSocket != null && ClientSocket.Connected)
        {
            ClientSocket.BeginSend(AddSize(data), 0, data.Length, 0, ResponseSend, this);
        }
        else
        {
            ConnectionFailed();
        }
    }
```

you send `data.Length` bytes out, but the `AddSize()` methods adds a `ushort` message-length field at the beginning of the buffer. The size of this field must be included in what is sent out.